# Заполнение свободного места в строке до конца строки

Tags: c++

Уже задавал сегодня похожий вопрос. Проблему решили. Но появилась ещё одна. Нужно заполнить первую строку символами до конца. Как это сделать? Типа, у меня есть первая строка, из неё удаляется 5 символов, и дальше она до конца (до 20) должна быть заполнена восклицательными знаками. Заполнять только пустые места.
Пример.

Ввод:

```
dvbccvb
```

Вывод:

```
vb!!!!!!!!!!!!!
```

Я думал, что можно как-то сделать это в отдельном цикле, но не получается... Он просто не заменяет никакие символы восклицательными знаками.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h> 

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    setlocale(0, "");

    char stroka1[20];
    char stroka2[20];
    cout << "Заполните символами первую строку -> ";
    std::cin.getline(stroka1, 20);
    cout << "Заполните символами вторую строку -> ";
    std::cin.getline(stroka2, 20);

    int i = 0;

    for (int q = 0; stroka1[q]; ++q) {
        if (stroka1[q] && q < 5) {
            char * to = stroka1, *from = stroka1+5;
            while(*to++ = *from++);
            i++;
        }
        else {
            break;
        }
    }

    for (; stroka1[i]; ++i) { 
        stroka1[i] = '!';
    }
    // вывожу содержимое этих строк
    std::cout << "Содержимое первой строки: " << stroka1 << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Содержимое второй строки: " << stroka2 << std::endl;

    // копирую первую строку во вторую
    strcat(stroka2, stroka1);

    std::cout << "Содержимое второй (результирующей) строки: " << stroka2 << std::endl;

    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: А вопросы по "До конца строки" уже задавали? или это до капасити???

Answer (score 2):

Как будто на С пишете, честное слово.

Проще так:

```
std::string str;
std::getline(std::cin, str);
str.resize(20, '!');
```

Comment: действительно: если есть  `#include <iostream>`, то это C++, а если так то почему не воспользоваться  его возможностьями?..

Comment: Если честно, то я не понимаю, как использовать и куда вставить эту конструкцию =(
Напишите, пожалуйста, куда это нужно вставить)

Comment: @RaisaTinina Идите читайте про `std::string`. В `main`, вместо всего его содержимого. Снизу подпишите `std::cout << str << '\n';`. Не забудьте `#include <string>`.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat если подключен iostream на linux string не нужен. на Win наверное тож

Comment: @Maggot Это не гарантируется стандартом и в любом случае это плохой стиль, имхо.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat нет, суть в реализации libstd++. iostream'у нужен string и он его подтягивает сам. Стандарт тут абсолютно не причем. лет 5 назад да. надо было включать. Но включать, да, надо, ибо у кого-то может быть старый и тупой компилятор.

Comment: @Maggot А весь ли `<string>` ему нужен? Думаю, ничего не мешает разрабам библиотеки реализовать сам `class basic_string` в одном файле, а, скажем, некоторые его перегруженные операторы - в другом, и из `<iostream>` инклудить только первый. (Может поэтому у вас на старых компиляторах не работало?) *"может быть старый и тупой компилятор"* Угу, или наоборот в каком-нибудь новом компиляторе сломается.